# Cannot get gridview child at index

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

I am using a `baseadapter` to add items in the `gridview`, I do this in 'onclick`event of a`listview`row. Data is collected and passed to the adapter in`arraylist` of custom object.

This is how I am doing it:

```
  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
    List<GVShow> lstGVShow = new ArrayList<GVShow>();
    //code to construct lstGVShow here..                
                    FragmentTvGuideMain.gridView.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(
                            FragmentTvGuideMain.context.getApplicationContext(),
                            lstGVShow)); //FragmentTvGuideMain.context = getActivity() in Fragmentactivity
```

This is my `gridviewadapter`:

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private final List lstGVShow;

```
public GridViewAdapter(Context context, List<GVShow> lstGVShow) {
    this.context = context;
    this.lstGVShow = lstGVShow;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = convertView;//new View(context);

        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_tile_layout,parent, false);

        TextView txtShowName = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.ShowTitle);
        TextView txtShowDuration = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.ShowTime);
        ImageButton imgBtnShow = (ImageButton) gridView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        GVShow show = lstGVShow.get(position);
        txtShowName.setText(show.getShowName());
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(show.getShowImage(), imgBtnShow);

    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lstGVShow.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

}

This is how I get the child from the `gridview` and it gives an `NPE`:

```
View rlNowPlaying = FragmentTvGuideMain.gridView.getChildAt(0); //done after setting the adapter

FragmentTvGuideMain.gridView.getCount(); //returns the correct number of views added in the gridview
```

It seems to me like some sort of a non-blocking call to set the views in baseadapter of the gridview. How do I go working around this?

Comment: why do you need `gridView.getChildAt(0)` ?

Comment: I need to get the `textviews`, `imagebuttons` added in the `gridview`, so that I can change the content in them using an `asynctask`

Comment: you could change the dataset and let android deal with the new data

Comment: I also have `progressbars` in the layout..